# Map not showing annotation

Tags: ios, mapkit, mapkitannotation

I am including an annotation to a mapView, but it is not shown.

The map appears and it is centered at the expected location. The map center coordinates are the same as the annotation coordinates.

Any help to detect where is the problem is welcome.

```
#import "mapKitViewController.h"
#import "Annotation.h"

@interface mapKitViewController ()

@end

//AYUNTAMIENTO DE LAS PALMAS DE GC
#define LP_LATITUDE 28.1249625;
#define LP_LONGITUDE -15.4286931;
//span
#define THE_SPAN 0.01f;



@implementation mapKitViewController
@synthesize myMapView;
- (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil
{
    self = [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil];
    if (self) {
        // Custom initialization
    }
    return self;
}

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    self.title = @"Localízame";    


    //DATOS DEL MAPA
    //region
    MKCoordinateRegion myRegion;

    //centro del mapa
    CLLocationCoordinate2D center;
    center.latitude = LP_LATITUDE;
    center.longitude = LP_LONGITUDE;

    //span
    MKCoordinateSpan span;
    span.latitudeDelta = THE_SPAN;
    span.longitudeDelta = THE_SPAN;

    myRegion.center = center;
    myRegion.span = span;

    [myMapView setRegion:myRegion animated:YES];

    //annotation
    CLLocationCoordinate2D ayuntamiento;
    ayuntamiento.latitude = LP_LATITUDE;
    ayuntamiento.longitude = LP_LONGITUDE;

    Annotation *aytoPin;
    aytoPin.coordinate = ayuntamiento;
    aytoPin.title = @"Ayuntamiento";
    aytoPin.subtitle = @"Las Palmas de Gran Canaria";
    [myMapView addAnnotation:aytoPin];
}
```

Comment: In addition to Matt's answer below, make sure you're setting the map view's delegate and implementing the delegate method `mapView:viewForAnnotation:`

Comment: @David, to display a default annotation (red pin), it is not necessary to set the delegate or implement viewForAnnotation.

Comment: @Anna but if he were using a default annotation, wouldn't he be using MKPointAnnotation? Presumably this is some special class of his own.

Comment: @matt, MKPointAnnotation and any class that implements the MKAnnotation protocol are just the _model_ objects that you are telling the map to add.  Their _view_ is something else (MKAnnotationView or its subclass).

Comment: Wasn't sure of that Anna, but in any case, the main issue is Matt's answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I do not know what Annotation is (instead of a built-in MKPointAnnotation or similar), but I assume that it is something that knows how to draw itself correctly.

The problem, then, is this:

```
Annotation *aytoPin;
aytoPin.coordinate = ayuntamiento;
```

You are not creating an Annotation (`alloc`, `init`). So `aytoPin` is nil, and nothing is happening. There is no object here.

(It is easy to get caught by this kind of mistake, because your subsequent messages are messages directed at nil, which is not an error in Objective-C. So nothing happens to alert you to the problem.)

Comment: Thank you matt, it was a beginners mistake. I have updated the line as follows. Annotation *aytoPin = [Annotation alloc]; and now it is shown....no need to init?? Annotation is a NSObject subclass.

Comment: Yes, you should use `[[Annotation alloc] init]` or `[Annotation new]` which is a synonym.

Comment: Never say `alloc` without saying `init`, and never say `init` except when saying `alloc` (or when implementing an `init`). :) See my discussion here: http://www.apeth.com/iOSBook/ch05.html#_instantiation_from_scratch NOTE: I do not know the initializer for your Annotation class; it may be that you have to supply more information.

Comment: My question is related to the tutorial I am following, there the programmer is using alloc without init... but I guess it is not completely right...

Comment: Wow, I wouldn't look any further at that tutorial if I were you!